# Keil debugger changes the hardware state of STM32H7 regarding FIFOs

Tags: stm32, keil, cortex-m

I encountered the following issue while using Keil MDK 5 for STM32H743.

I had a communication problem with my SPI code and after a while I found out that it was due to the Periodic Windows Update.

When it is activated, it seems that the debugger is reading regularly the SPI data register, which reads the FIFO (so changes the state of the FIFO). Consequently when the software reads the FIFO, some bytes have been "lost" (or consumed by the debugger).

Is it an expected behaviour ? Do you know if it is due to Keil or to the STM32 ?

I don't fully understand how an access from the debugger to a register is working: I guess there is a read command sent over SWD but then, internally does the access to memory go through AHB / APB like for code executing on the CPU ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any registers that modify behaviour by being read (such as clearing status bits) can be problematic when debugging and the registers are shown in the debug window.

The best bet is to only look at the registers when you stop (close the DR window for the peripheral), and always be aware that you may clear status bits etc.

It is the way the processor works and nothing to do with the debugger.

It is a very common debug issue with serial comms etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you have DR display in your  watch window (or any other similar windows on the debugger screen) and you step through the code every time you step (or generally break) the data is read.

That is the only possible reason.

Comment: I don't break or step, I just let the code run. SPI_DR is displayed only in the peripheral register window provided by Keil.

Comment: So how do you think this window takes the data from it? How this magical window is different from watch window? Using it it is one of the most common debugging mistakes. When debugger reads this register to display, it takes it from the FIFO.

Comment: I don't say it's different, I only answer to your comment.

Comment: I would expect the debugger is smart enough to not read FIFOs or other registers that change the state of the hardware.

Comment: how can debuger know what changes and what not? For any possible supported chip.

Comment: it already has a mapping of all peripheral registers. doesn't look that complicated to just not access some registers

Comment: BTW if it limits the access it would be one of stupidest thing debugger designers can do. Debuggers are for developers who know what they are doing, they cannot limit them.